# I need to run this function twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have tried for loops, etc, but i am having trouble running this function only twice

```
            function play() {
                setInterval(function(){
                    var next = $(".furniture .active, .pets .active").next("img");
                    var i = 0;
                    var current = next.prev("img");
                    current.removeClass("active").addClass("current")
                    next.removeClass("current").addClass("active");
                    if (!next.length) {
                        next = $(".furniture img:first");
                        };
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }   
            play();
```

Comment: What problems are you having? error messages? etc?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: If you mean the anonymous function called by setInterval, it will run every 3 seconds forever until you call clearInterval.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want something like this:

```
function play(timeout) { 
  setTimeout(function() {
    ...
  }, timeout);
}
play(3000);
play(6000);
```

Comment: I think `setTimeout` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = 0;

play();

function play()
{
    counter = counter + 1;

    var next = $(".furniture .active, .pets .active").next("img");
                    var i = 0;
                    var current = next.prev("img");
                    current.removeClass("active").addClass("current")
                    next.removeClass("current").addClass("active");
                    if (!next.length) {
                        next = $(".furniture img:first");
                        };
                    }

    if (counter < 2)
    {        
        setTimeout(play(), 3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more what i am looking for, but is not working when i plug it in. classes aren't changing